# Azure Function App - How to upgrade .NET runtime

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I currently have an Azure Function app created as a .NET 7 LTS isolated runtime stack. I'm running Consumption (Serverless) in Linux.

I've upgraded my codebase to .NET 8. How can I update my existing Function App to .NET 8 before deploying my new relase?

[image: Existing Azure Function app]

Comment: I was in the same situation as this, NET 7 Isolated on Linux Consumption. I had to delete the Function App and create a new one where you could specify NET 8. Certainly there is a better way than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to upgrade my Function App using Azure CLI

```
az functionapp config set --name <APP_NAME> --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --linux-fx-version "DOTNET-ISOLATED|8.0
```

The `General settings` page was not available. I don't if that because it's Consumption (Serverless) plan or because it is running in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration section of the Function App:
[image]

Comment: For some reason, I do not have the "General settings" section here, which seems to be because I'm running Consumption (Serverless).

Answer (score 1):

As [Tanuki mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77505925/4477336) you need version in Stack settings. But in my case, `Stack settings` was not even visible. I had to migrate function worker to isolated mode.

You can easily (but not intuitively) done it by setting `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` option in the Application setting to `dotnet-isolated` (previously it was `dotnet`).

[image]

Save and the Stack settings will magically appear.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh yes - this would make sense since other .net versions are only supported for "dotnet-isolated"